# Node.js i unzipped txt.gz and cant read txt after it

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have some problem with reading data from text file after i unzipped it the code:

```
const fileContents = fs.createReadStream('/root/khbot/players/player.txt.gz');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/root/khbot/players/player.txt');
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);

    const data = fs.readFileSync('/root/khbot/players/player.txt','utf8');
```

The data is empty every time , something need to be closed because seems like the file still opened by fs?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

If you use streams in Node.js, keep in mind that they are working asynchronously. When you invoke `fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream)`, it returns directly before the streams have finished their jobs. The reading, piping and writing is done asynchronously, i.e. after all functions from the code-block in your post have returned synchronously.

So, the problem is that you act too early when you try to read the file contents. Before you can do so, you have to wait until the write-stream has emitted a "finish" event.

### Solution

If you can use `await` (e.g. because the given code is inside an `async function`), you could add such an additional line before the last statement:

```js
const fileContents = fs.createReadStream("/root/khbot/players/player.txt.gz");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`/root/khbot/players/player.txt`);
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);

await new Promise(resolve => writeStream.on("finish", resolve));

const data = fs.readFileSync(`/root/khbot/players/player.txt`, "utf8");
```

The following solution works without Promise and async/await, but is still asynchronous. Using a callback is kind of the old way to do it:

```js
const fileContents = fs.createReadStream('/root/khbot/players/player.txt.gz');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/root/khbot/players/player.txt');
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);

writeStream.on("finish", () => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync('/root/khbot/players/player.txt','utf8');

  ...
});
```

### Alternative solution

Listening to events you can even skip writing the textfile to your disk. Code like the following will unzip the file and deliver the content directly to your variable `data`:

#### with async/await and Promise

```js
const fileContents = fs.createReadStream("/root/khbot/players/player.txt.gz");
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip);

const data = await new Promise(resolve => {
  const chunks = [];
  unzip.on("data", chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
  unzip.on("finish", () => resolve(chunks.join("")));
});

...
```

#### without async/await and Promise

```js
const fileContents = fs.createReadStream("/root/khbot/players/player.txt.gz");
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip);

const chunks = [];
unzip.on("data", chunk => chunks.push(chunk));

unzip.on("finish", () => {
  const data = chunks.join("");

  ...
});
```